# Do I need to open the chest to make it count as a win?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

If instead of opening the chest I skipped it and used one of the methods to access Sheol directly (I am error room; Devil room; We need to go deeper) does it still count as a victory as far as the main menu endings list, the item unlocks and everything else goes?

Answer (score 1):

It does count as a win so the credits will be unlocked and can be viewed in the stats screen but they are not displayed immediately. If you beat the next boss you will see their credits instead.